# I am imitating of Pocoyo smile

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

He watched Pocoyo.

Pocoyo smiled in the cartoon.

He was imitating him smile.

> "I am imitating of Pocoyo smile."
>
> "I am imitating Pocoyo smile."

He said.

Do I need to add "of" after imitating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"He was imitating him smile."  is incorrect.  Some correct examples:

> He was imitating *his* smile. (if the emphasis is on the smile itself)
>
> He was imitating him *smiling*. (if the emphasis is on the act of smiling)
>
> He was imitating *his smiling* (if the emphasis is on the act of specifically Pocoyo smiling)

Or as a direct quote:

> "I am imitating Pocoyo's smile," he said.  (first use, above)
>
> "I am imitating Pocoyo's smiling," he said.  (second use, above)
>
> "I am imitating how Pocoyo smiles," he said.  (third use, above)